# How to check whether $\int^1_0\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}+x^5}dx$ converges by comparison test?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I need to determine by the comparison test whether the following integral converges over $[0,1]$:

$$\int^1_0\frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}+x^5}dx$$

What I tried:

I tried comparing it to:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+x^6}\geq \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}+x^5}$ (on $[0,1]$) but the integral diverges.

I then compared it to :

$\frac{1}{x+x^{\frac{1}{4}}} \leq \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}+x^5}$ but the integral converges.

I'm not sure whether i'm approaching this in the right way ( I've tried checking more integrals which are less or bigger but to no avail).

What integrals would you suggest comparing it to? I'm struggling to find any. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In fact, $\int_0^1\frac1{x^{1/3}+x^5}\,\mathrm{d}x\le\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^{1/3}+x^5}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{3\pi}{14}\csc(\pi/7)$

Comment: @robjohn. For the given integral, the result is quite nice too.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I get $\frac32\left(1+\frac{H_{1/7}-H_{1/14}-\log(2)}7\right)\approx1.3732192902564023721$

Comment: which is $\frac3{14}(\psi(1/7)-\psi(1/14)-\log(2))$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{1/3}}dx$? It converges.

Comment: ah yes, i can't believe i haven't seen this trivial one in my head. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using *asymptotic analysis*, it is very simple:

We know that  near $0$, $x^5=o\bigl(x^{1/3}\bigr)$ so
$$ x^{1/3}+x^5\sim_0 x^{1/3},\quad\text{whence }\quad\frac1{x^{1/3}+x^5}\sim_0\frac 1{x^{1/3}} $$
and $\;\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac {\mathrm dx}{x^{1/3}} $ is convergent.

Comment: What does $o\bigl(x^{1/3}\bigr)$ mean?

and what does $\sim_0$ mean?

Comment: $o(x^{1/3})$ means the ratio  $\frac{x^5}{ x^{1/3}} $  tends to $0$ (here, when $x$ tends to $0$). $\sim_0$ is the standard notation to specify two functions are equivalent near $0$, i.e.  their ratio tends to $1$ when $x$ tends to $0$. A theorem asserts that the improper integrals of two equivalent functions both converge or both diverge, so the strategy  consists in finding a simpler equivalent function for which it is easy to conclude.

Comment: just to clarify, did you mean to write $o(x^{1/3})$ means the ratio $\frac{x^5}{ x^{1/3}}$ tends to $1$? or $0$?

Comment: It tends to $0$.

Comment: @Marina: $f(x)=O(g(x))\implies\frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)}\le C$ whereas $f(x)=o(g(x))\implies\frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)}\to0$.

Comment: @robjohn thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$f(x):=\frac{1}{x^{1/3}+x^5} \le \frac{1}{x^{1/3}}=:g(x).$

$\int_{a}^{1}f(x)dx \le \int_{a}^{1}g(x)dx$, $a>0$;

$\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{a}^{1}g(x)dx =A>0$.

$\int_{a}^{1}f(x)dx$ is bounded above by $A,$ and increasing as $a \rightarrow 0^+$, hence convergent.